# Adding GridView in literal control C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
<asp:Literal ID="ltrEOGrid" runat="server"></asp:Literal>

protected void Page_Init(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
    string Grid = "<eo:Grid ID=\"Grid1\" runat=\"server\"> <Columns>           <eo:TextBoxColumn HeaderText=\"1010\" DataField=\"1010\"></eo:TextBoxColumn></Columns></eo:Grid> ";
    ltrEOGrid.Text = Grid;
}
```

how to bind gridview id throgh DataSource.
just like

```
Grid1.DataSource = dt;
Grid1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use PlaceHolder control, not string.

Look:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.placeholder(v=vs.110).aspx